# How do I create a 'last seen at' time of when a user was last online?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-firebase

I want to add a `last seen at today 1pm` or the time when a user last visited or opened my app - a feature like WhatsApp and other chat apps have.

In my React Native chat app I used redux for state handling. I am using Firebase for my backend. My chat app is almost complete but I don’t know how to add a user last seen feature.

Comment: You will probably get flagged for asking the question, because it doesn't follow a good format for Stack Overflow. Totally understandable since you're new here! You should edit the question with this: 1. describe the precise problem you are trying to solve (i have no clue what "last seen" means). 2. describe the research and methods you've tried so far. 3. Ask a specific question about implementation - currently your question is a little vague. 4. Provide information about how your app is set up (like your data model for chats). We can't help you with so little information :)

Answer (score 5):

You can make use of Firebase Realtime Databases [onDisconnect API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.OnDisconnect) to build a presence system, e.g. detect when a user was last online.

The following example includes a users state, e.g. `online` or `offline`, as well as a `last_changed` timestamp. You can use a combination of both of these to create a rich presence status for each user in your chat app.

```js
import firebase from 'react-native-firebase';

// Fetch the current user's ID from Firebase Authentication.
const uid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;

// Create a reference to this user's specific status node.
// This is where we will store data about being online/offline.
const userStatusRef = firebase.database().ref('/status/' + uid);

// We'll create two constants which we will write to 
// the Realtime database when this device is offline
// or online.
const isOfflineForDatabase = {
    state: 'offline',
    last_changed: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP,
};

const isOnlineForDatabase = {
    state: 'online',
    last_changed: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP,
};

// Create a reference to the special '.info/connected' path in 
// Realtime Database. This path returns `true` when connected
// and `false` when disconnected.
firebase.database().ref('.info/connected').on('value', (snapshot) => {
    // If we're not currently connected, don't do anything.
    if (snapshot.val() == false) {
        return;
    };

    // If we are currently connected, then use the 'onDisconnect()' 
    // method to add a set which will only trigger once this 
    // client has disconnected by closing the app, 
    // losing internet, or any other means.
    userStatusRef.onDisconnect().set(isOfflineForDatabase).then(() => {
        // The promise returned from .onDisconnect().set() will
        // resolve as soon as the server acknowledges the onDisconnect() 
        // request, NOT once we've actually disconnected:
        // https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.OnDisconnect

        // We can now safely set ourselves as 'online' knowing that the
        // server will mark us as offline once we lose connection.
        userStatusRef.set(isOnlineForDatabase);
    });
});
```

Sample code adapted from: [presence guide - Firebase website](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/presence).

Hope that helps.