# React App on Firebase - Fetching User Last Login Time

Tags: reactjs, firebase, authentication, oauth-2.0, oauth

I have a React App hosted in Firebase. I'm tring to get "lastLoginAt" information of the user. I can get this via Firebase Auth Rest API "Get user data" but problem is FIREBASE_ID_TOKEN is needed at sample request.

```
curl 'https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:lookup?key=[API_KEY]' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-binary '{"idToken":"[FIREBASE_ID_TOKEN]"}'
```

In order to get FIREBASE_ID_TOKEN, user have to be logged in but then this overwrites "lastLoginAt" value and makes it useless for my case. Maybe I should look for another data elsewhere but I'm not very experienced in Firebase.

Another thing I tried was trying to import firebase-admin to my app, but as it is a browser based client side app it is not possible. Then for the last I authenticated a user via this separate js standalone module which worked fine;

```
import admin            from "firebase-admin"
import serviceAccount   from "./serviceAccountKey.json" assert { type: "json" } // Initialize the Firebase Admin SDK with your project credentials

admin.initializeApp({
    
    credential  : admin.credential.cert( serviceAccount ),
    databaseURL : 'DATABASE_URL'
});

// Get a reference to the Firebase Authentication user management API
const auth = admin.auth()

// Set custom claims for the user that grant the necessary permissions to retrieve user information
const uid = 'UID_USER' // The UID of the user to authorize

const customClaims = {
    
    authorizedUser: true // A custom claim that grants permission to retrieve user information
}

auth.setCustomUserClaims( uid, customClaims)
    
    .then(() => {
        
        console.log( 'User authorized successfully' );
    })
    
    .catch(error => {
        
        console.error( error );
    })
```

With this authorized user I tried to grab last login time of users without these users logging in and overwriting their lastloginat values.

The curl API call I tried was;

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:lookup?key=APP_KEY' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer LOOOONG_TOKEN'
```

Finally this gave me following reply;

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 401,
        "message": "Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
        "errors": [
            {
                "message": "Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
                "domain": "global",
                "reason": "unauthorized"
            }
        ],
        "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
    }
}
```

I know I can do this in another way by recording login times to a DB table and fetching them but knowing that this data is already available tickles me to do it trough Firebase. Anyone has an idea what else can I try or what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Important note: The Firebase Admin SDK should **never** be used from a public client side application. It bypasses all user protections, rate-limiting, and has unrestricted access to your databases where it can read, update and delete any data stored in them. If you need to bring certain privileged actions to the public client side app, you should make use of [Callable Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) to gate their use to a handful of users and implement strict data validation on each call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to track when the user was last active, take a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51898007/3068190).

---

If you are looking to track when users actually log in, you'll need to write to the RTDB/Firestore immediately after a call to a `signIn*` method with the value of `new Date(currentUser.metadata.lastSignInTime).getTime()` (reference: [Legacy SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.auth.UserMetadata#lastsignintime) / [Modern SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.usermetadata)). As long as that user doesn't need to call another `signIn` method, their old `lastLoginAt` time won't change.

```
// Legacy syntax
import * as firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/auth";
import "firebase/database";

const auth = firebase.auth();
const rtdb = firebase.database();

const { user } = await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);

await rtdb.ref("users/" + user.uid + "/lastLoginAt")
  .set(new Date(user.metadata.lastSignInTime).getTime());
```

```
// Modern syntax
import { getAuth, signInWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";
import { getDatabase, ref, set } from "firebase/database";

const auth = getAuth();
const rtdb = getDatabase();

const { user } = await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);

await set(
  ref(rtdb, "users/" + user.uid + "/lastLoginAt"),
  new Date(user.metadata.lastSignInTime).getTime()
);
```

---

If the intent is to track how many days ago the user last logged in, instead of using a basic `set` operation, update the new login time using a transaction:

```
// Legacy syntax
import * as firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/auth";
import "firebase/database";

const auth = firebase.auth();
const rtdb = firebase.database();

const { user } = await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);

let previousLoginTime;
await rtdb.ref("users/" + user.uid + "/lastLoginAt")
  .transaction((serverPreviousLoginTime) => {
    previousLoginTime = serverPreviousLoginTime;
    return new Date(user.metadata.lastSignInTime).getTime();
  });

// previousLoginTime now contains the previous login, in milliseconds, if any (it can be null).
if (previousLoginTime) {
  console.log("User's last login: " + String(new Date(previousLoginTime)));
}
```

```
// Modern syntax
import { getAuth, signInWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";
import { getDatabase, ref, runTransaction } from "firebase/database";

const auth = getAuth();
const rtdb = getDatabase();

const { user } = await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);

let previousLoginTime;
await runTransaction(
  ref(rtdb, "users/" + user.uid + "/lastLoginAt"),
  (serverPreviousLoginTime) => {
    previousLoginTime = serverPreviousLoginTime;
    return new Date(user.metadata.lastSignInTime).getTime();
  });
);

// previousLoginTime now contains the previous login, in milliseconds, if any (it can be null).
if (previousLoginTime) {
  console.log("User's last login: " + String(new Date(previousLoginTime)));
}
```

---

If the intent is to track recent login sessions, you can alternatively push data to the database rather than overwrite it.

```
// Legacy syntax
import * as firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/auth";
import "firebase/database";

const auth = firebase.auth();
const rtdb = firebase.database();

const { user } = await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);

await rtdb.ref("userLogins/" + user.uid)
  .push({
    timestamp: new Date(user.metadata.lastSignInTime).getTime()
    /* ... other data? ... */,
  });
```

```
// Modern syntax
import { getAuth, signInWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";
import { getDatabase, ref, push } from "firebase/database";

const auth = getAuth();
const rtdb = getDatabase();

const { user } = await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);

await push(
  ref(rtdb, "userLogins/" + user.uid),
  {
    timestamp: new Date(user.metadata.lastSignInTime).getTime()
    /* ... other data? ... */,
  }
);
```

---

With the release of Cloud Functions v2, you also create a [`beforeUserSignedIn`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta/auth-blocking-events) function to handle the same logic discussed above. In most situations, the code above can be reused by swapping out `"firebase/*"` for `"firebase-admin/*"`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @samthecodingman. In my case it is enough for me to track when the user was last active. When I have time I'll check the post you pointed and confirm that your solution worked for my case. Have a great day :)